# How to create a Node Info Bar (or Node Info Block)?

Tags: theming, nodes, 8, navigation

I want to create a teaser with 3 sections:

1. **Title Section.**
2. **Information Section (Info Bar):**

   1. When this Node Writed? (Date & Time).
   2. Whom is writed this Node: (Author of Node).
   3. What category consist this: (taxonamy or category).
   4. How Many Viewed (Node View Statistics).
   5. How many add Comment (Comment Statistics).
3. **Show only "Read more" Linke:** at the bottom of a node teaser and remove or unset other links like the "Add New Comment", "2 New Comments", "2 Comments" at the end of a node teaser,
   because I dont think it makes good sense for people to comment on something that they haven't read yet.

I want to achieve something like the following picture:

[image: Node Info Bar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey, you wanted a parallel full stack solution, here it is:

You create a new content type:

[image]

You should hide the "view count" field from the form display:

[image]

Here is the display for teaser:

[image]

You need to do some node preprocess in your custom theme (test.theme):

```
function test_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['node']->bundle() == 'my_bounty_content' && $variables['teaser']) {
    _test_preprocess_my_content_teaser($variables);
  }
}

function _test_preprocess_my_content_teaser(&$variables) {
  $variables['content']['field_category'] = $variables['elements']['field_category']['0']['#title'];
  $variables['content']['field_view_count'] = $variables['elements']['field_view_count']['0']['#markup'];
  $comment_count = $variables['node']->get('field_comments')->comment_count;
  $variables['content']['comments_count'] = $comment_count ? $comment_count : 0;
}
```

You also need the functionality to increase the node view stats by each visit. 
Put this code into your custom module '.module' file:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_view().
 */
function base_entity_view(array &$build, \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity, \Drupal\Core\Entity\Display\EntityViewDisplayInterface $display, $view_mode) {
  if ($entity->getEntityTypeId() == 'node' && $entity->bundle() == 'my_bounty_content' && $view_mode == 'full') {
    $view_count = (int) $entity->get('field_view_count')->getString();
    $entity->set('field_view_count', ++$view_count);
    $entity->save();
  }
}
```

And finally create a new template file for your content teaser in your custom theme directory under 'templates' directory:

node--my-bounty-content--teaser.html.twig

```
<article>
    <h2>
        {{ label }}
    </h2>
    <ul class="meta">
        <li>{{ author_name }}</li>
        <li>{{ date }}</li>
        <li>{{ content.field_category }}</li>
        <li>Viewed: {{ content.field_view_count }}</li>
        <li>Comments: {{ content.comments_count }}</li>
    </ul>
    <div>{{ content.body }}</div>
    <a href="{{ url }}">{{ 'Read more'|trans  }}</a>

</article>
```

After this, you only need to list your nodes with teaser view. STILL the views module is the best solution for this, I didn't wrote custom code for this. 
If you need, let me know I will both post hardcore, and views example for that.

Adding custom theme, library, css is NOT included here.

Remember to clear cache between testing new hooks, templates and so on.

Answer (score 4):

**Views** module covers pretty much everything you want. You only have have to solve "node views count" somehow (extra field, hidden from display).

Comment: Thanks you so much, But i dont want to use views module, Is there any other module for this purpose only?

Comment: Maybe Panels could be a solution for this, but View would be the most common one. Personally I also would go for custom solution, hardcoding it (based on node display, using the render function).

Comment: `But i dont want to use views module, Is there any other module for this purpose only?` @Arash there is no reason for anyone to build a module for this when Views already does this. You have something against views? Your only other option would be to build a custom module yourself.